# Logging the Instruction Pointer Register

Tags: debuggers, tools

Is there a tool that logs the value the IP register of a specific process running?
I am trying to compare the instruction excution before and after a file modification.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the CPU architecture the process targets, there are many *dynamic instrumentation* tools that can perform this function. However, you have not specified the environment the process of interest runs in.

Architecture-specific examples:

- Intel's pintool. Someone on stackoverflow has already asked about how to use pintool to [print all executed instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478420/log-all-instruction-with-intel-pintool)
- [PANDA](https://github.com/panda-re/panda/blob/master/panda/docs/manual.md#recordreplay-details). This framework includes a plugin called `PANDA_CB_INSN_TRANSLATE` which is triggered prior to instruction translation and can be paired with `PANDA_CB_INSN_EXEC`
- The DynamoRIO-based tool [instrace](https://github.com/DynamoRIO/dynamorio/blob/master/api/samples/instrace_x86.c). "instrace" is short for "instruction trace".